# 'For Each' VB.NET iteration count

Tags: vb.net

Does a [`For Each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5ebk1751.aspx) loop in Visual Basic have an iteration count, or would I have to do that myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to do that yourself.  The `For Each` construct uses an implementation the [`IEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) interface to iterate a sequence and the `IEnumerator` interface does not expose any members to indicate its position or current index within the sequence.

Comment: Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 8):

If I need an iterator variable, I use a `for` loop instead (every IEnumerable should have a .Count property).

Instead of

```
For Each element as MyType in MyList
    ....
Next
```

write

```
For i as integer = 0 to MyList.Count - 1
    element = MyList(i)
    ....
Next
```

which will be the same result. You have `i` as an iterator and `element` holds the current element.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio 2009 (or VB.Net 9.0), you can use a Select override to get a count with the values.

```
For Each cur in col.Select(Function(x,i) New With { .Index = i, .Value = x })
 ...
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do it yourself. Mostly, if you're doing For Each (foreach in C#), then you don't care about iteration count.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loops for each element M it finds in a collection of M elements.

So, no, there is no explicit iteration count as there would be in a FOR loop.